# Continuously Move Around Spline with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

With the Evaluate Spline mode, as you move the parameter towards 1, the object moves to the end of the spline. How could you make the Suzanne continuously move around the spline, such that once it reaches the end of the spline, it starts to move the beginning, in a looping fashion?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Modulo** math operation:

[image]